# What color are Dumbledore's glasses' frames (in the novels)?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

Have the Harry Potter novels ever given a color for the frames of Dumbledore's glasses?

Basically every time they've been referenced, they've been called "half-moon" shaped, but never with a description of the color.

I've seen a lot of quotes about his glasses and I presume they're gold but is that just a movie thing?

Quotes such as:

> Dumbledore lowered his hands and surveyed Harry through his half-moon glasses.
>
> Order of the Phoenix

Comment: I thought that the question was what color were the lenses of the glasses tinted, but I guess that the frame could be a much more vivid color than the lenses that had to be transparent.

Comment: Lenses or frames?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Dumbledore wears **gold**, half-moon glasses.

> Something gold was glinting just above him. The Snitch! He tried to catch it, but his arms were too heavy.
>
> He blinked. It wasn’t the Snitch at all. It was a pair of glasses. How strange.
>
> He blinked again. The smiling face of Albus Dumbledore swam into view above him.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</sup></sub>

Presumably they were similar to these

[image]

Comment: Wow! So fast! ... I wonder if this was the only mention of their color. Well, if this is gonna be the only answer after a few days, this is a pretty good one!

Comment: I'm chuckling imagining Harry catching Dumbledore's glasses as if it was a snitch.

Comment: +1 for the [Red Freehand Circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/662798)

Comment: +1 for the image of Albus Dumbledore choosing his spectacle frames at an NHS optician.

Comment: @MikeHarris - All of the spectacles in Harry Potter seem to come off of this board.

Comment: @MikeHarris - let's hope he waited for a "free pair of prescription sunglasses" deal, to really stretch out his NHS voucher.

Comment: @TomGoodfellow - He should have gone to HexSavers